# CMOS active crystal oscillator output voltage uncertainty

Tags: voltage, oscillator, pll, reference

I want to use SG7050CAN CMOS active crystal oscillator as reference input to ADF4106 PLL. The input voltage level is 0.8/AVDD Vp-p min/max.

Now, the SG7050CAN datasheet says, it's low voltage is 0.4 V max, high voltage is 0.4-VDD V. Now, if the low voltage is 0.3 V, the high voltage is 0.5 V, I get only 0.2 Vp-p. It's no good for us.

I need at least 1 Vp-p to be safe. The datasheet gives the range 0.4-VDD. I will be using VDD 3.3 V. So, if the device stays somewhere around the middle of the range, we get low voltage ~0.2 V, high voltage ~1.4. So, we get ~1.2 Vp-p. Which is good.

But will the device stay in the middle? If no, then what do I do?

Datasheet of the devices:

SG7050CAN:

https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/download/653076/EPSON/SG7050CAN.html

ADF4106:

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADF4106.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You indicated "the high voltage is 0.5 V"
The spec says Voh=Vdd-0.4 @ 15 pF so for Vdd=1.6V your worst-case is max f with only 0.8V guaranteed swing or 50% centred at Vdd/2.

**Assumption**: you understand the RdsOn curve with CMOS FETs and when load = source output is 50% at 15 pF STD LOAD of no-load output. (0 pF)

[image]

If you examine datasheets of 5.5V logic and compare Zol=Vol/Iol at different voltages from 1.8 to 4.5V (5V-10%) with tolerances, you can appreciate the Zout or RdsOn range. and > 25% tolerance at room temp.

Some suppliers like NXP may be better than others yet all are similar by design for reasons of shoot-thru, and switched Ciss,Coss * Miller capacitance. It is never discussed in datasheets but it is the reason why every CMOS must have a small Vdd decoupling cap. Although at 1.8V the impedance is much higher than at 5V.

**Note the tiny 15 pF text at bottom-centre for the frequency load-line of 15 pF.  When that matches the source impedance, Vout = 50% of no load.**

Comment: Oh man. It was VCC-0.4 V, meaning VCC MINUS 0.4 V. I was reading VCC-0.4 V, meaning VCC TO 0.4 V. My bad.

Comment: I actually do not have knowledge of the CMOS theories, thanks for your effort explaining.

Comment: Just read  about any FET Rdson vs Vgs-Vt curve where Vgs=Vdd here and Vt= Vgs(th) the drain leakage threshold for the gate to source threshold .

Answer (score 1):

The reference clock input to the ADF4106 should be AC-coupled with an appropriate series capacitor, and the input circuitry for the reference clock includes a self-biased inverter that keeps the signal centered around the appropriate common mode:

[image]

If you drive the oscillator at 1.6 V, you will have a swing between 0.4 V and 1.2 V, barely satisfying the requirement. By using a higher supply voltage, you will have a large enough swing, and the AC coupling at the PLL will ensure that the signal is usable in spite of the higher common-mode from the oscillator.

For example, with both components running at 3.3V, the output of the oscillator will swing at least as wide as 0.4V - 2.9V (a swing of 1.5Vpp), which is within the input requirements. If the output doesn't "stay in the middle" (e.g. if it ranges from 0.1 V to 2.9 V, that's not an issue either. You'll just get a 1.8Vpp clock which will still get AC coupled and biased to the correct DC level at the reference input circuitry of the PLL.

Note that the input capacitance of the PLL is 10 pF, and the max allowable capacitance for the oscillator is 15 pF, so you'll need to be fairly careful with your layout to stay well within the spec. However, because you have a bit of headroom as far as signal swing, you can probably afford to relax a bit and run over the 15pF limit, even with the maximum oscillator frequency of 72 MHz.

Comment: Man. It was VCC-0.4 V, meaning VCC MINUS 0.4 V. I was reading VCC-0.4 V, meaning VCC TO 0.4 V. My bad.

Comment: @shafik No worries, I learned a few new things while glancing at the datasheets in order to write this answer so I really appreciate the question! The confusion really encouraged me to validate my assumptions carefully before answering.

Comment: I doubt there are any issues at 24 MHz rated at 3 times the frequency will not be 50% loss from no load but rather only 1/3 of 50% loss or in other words >=83%  Rail to rail at 24 MHz which exceeds all CMOS Vil Vih requirements The specs are 15 pF load only. .With 10 pF load the output loss reduces another 50 % to 91% full scale.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Amended. I didn't see that the frequency was that much lower than the max.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Actually, I'm not sure I follow where the 50% loss comes from. It would be 50% power loss if and only if the specified 15 pF * Rout provided a dominant pole at Fmax. I agree with everything else in principle, aside from what looks like an assumed 3 dB loss.

Comment: 1/3 the frequency is ALOT . It means 15 pF = 141 Ohms @ 75 MHz and 424 Ohms at 25 Mhz from a worst case 140 ohm Zs at 1.6V at 25'C the attenuation ratio is much smaller. 50% was from Vol= 0.4, Voh=Vdd-0.4 ~ 1.6V @ 15 pF  thus 0.8V swing with 1.6 no load rail to rail

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'm still not following where you selected those numerical values, specifically the 1/3 of a frequency. The oscillator Fmax is 72 MHz. The PLL will take a reference clock up to 200 MHz. The OP could want to operate the oscillator all the way at its Fmax. I understand the remainder of the claim, just not the assumption being made.

Comment: The uncertainty was only on the 25 MHz XO Output to PLL Input which his rated from 1 MHz to 75 MHz on the CAN part and 170 MHz on the CBN part which implies lower RdsOn. So you may have made some false interpretations in your understanding of the datasheet. or else I made a brain fart

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet says about the REF input pin that "This input can be driven from a TTL or CMOS crystal oscillator".

And that's what you are doing, you have a CMOS oscillator.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I was mistakenly reading VCC-0.4 V as VCC TO 0.4 V,  while it was actually, VCC MINUS 0.4 V.